# Instance Variables in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm trying to learn the absolute basics of Ruby on Rails following the Ruby on Rails guide. However, I'm having a problem trying to display a variable initialized in the controller, in the view: both in test and show views it says "undefined method for nil:NilClass"

`app/controllers/articles_controller`

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def test
    @testing = [0, 1, 2, 3]
  end

end



app/views/articles/new.html.haml

= form_for :article, :url => articles_path do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :title
    %br/
    = f.text_field :title
  %p
    = f.label :text
    %br/
    = f.text_field :title
  %p
    = f.submit



app/views/articles/show.html.haml

%p 
  Title:
  %br/
  = @article.title
%p
  Text:
  %br/
  = @article.text


app/views/articles/test.html.haml

= @testing[0]
```

This is the error I get for the show view:

```
NoMethodError in ArticlesController#show
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

 Title:
%br/
= @article.title
%p
Text:
%br/
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I don't see what I'm missing. Thanks

Comment: I have responded about the `@article`. `@testing` seems ok - can you paste the exact error you are getting and your routes as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using @article in the controller, and @articles in the view. Change @articles to @article in the view.

Also, move the private method to the bottom of the class - the show and test methods are now private in your controller.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def test
    @testing = [0, 1, 2, 3]
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

Comment: What is not working? What error do you get? Paste the entire error message.

Comment: Thank you very much ! The problem was with the methods being private